# How to add empty element to CMake list?

Tags: cmake

There is CMake script:

```
unset(FOO)
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(LENGTH FOO SIZE)
message(FATAL_ERROR ${SIZE})
```

Expectation - 4. Reality - 0

I've found a workaround, but it looks like a kludge:

```
set(FOO "dummy")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
set(FOO "${FOO};")
list(REMOVE_AT FOO 0)
message(FATAL_ERROR ${SIZE})
```

The example a little bit simpler than my task, so, please, don't suggest writing `set(FOO ";;;")`:) I get elements from outside, and some of them may be empty. Something like this:

```
function(do_smth LIST_WITH_EMPTY_ITEMS)
    unset(RESULT)
    foreach(X IN LISTS LIST_WITH_EMPTY_ITEMS)
        if(${CONDITION})
            list(APPEND RESULT "${X}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Comment: What's the actual use case for an empty element in a list?

Comment: @lubgr, I want to create a function, that returns each n'th element. `nth_items("1;2;3;4;5;6;7" 1 3 RESULT) #RESULT = 1;4;7`. And I don't want to "swallow" empty elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work with empty lists, but if you initialize the list with some dummy value, as you did in your second example `set(FOO "dummy")`, you can continue to use `FOO` as a list and also append empty elements to it. It's basically your desired approach and workaround combined:

```
set(FOO "dummy")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(APPEND FOO "")
list(POP_FRONT FOO)

list(LENGTH FOO SIZE)
message("content: (${FOO})")
message("sizt: ${SIZE}")
```

The output of this is:

```
content: (;;;)
size: 4
```